# What is the root of the non-trace-preserving bit-flip map

Tags: quantum-operation, information-theory, kraus-representation

I have a quantum channel defined by the Kraus operators:
$$
U_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
p & 0 \\
0 & p
\end{bmatrix},\quad
U_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & p \\
p & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
i.e.
$$
U_1\rho U_1^* + U_2\rho U_2^*.
$$
Now I want to find the square root of this channel i.e. a channel that applied twice results in the given channel. Of course, this can be solved via a system of equations but is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: related on math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4309848/173147

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming w.l.o.g. that $p\in\mathbb{R}$, the linear map in the question may be rewritten as

$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho) = p^2\rho+p^2X\rho X = 2p^2\left(\frac12\rho + \frac12 X\rho X\right)
$$

where $X$ is the Pauli matrix. Thus, the action of $\mathcal{E}$ can be understood as the composition $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{S}_{2p^2}\circ\mathcal{X}_{\frac12}$ of a scaling map $\mathcal{S}_{2p^2}$ and a bit-flip map $\mathcal{X}_{1/2}$ where

$$
\mathcal{S}_{a}(\rho)=a\rho \\
\mathcal{X}_{b}(\rho)=(1-b)\rho + bX\rho X.
$$

Now, since the two maps commute we try to take the square roots independently. Moreover, it is easy to see that

$$
\mathcal{S}_a\circ\mathcal{S}_{a'}=\mathcal{S}_{aa'} \\
\mathcal{X}_{1/2}\circ\mathcal{X}_{1/2}=\mathcal{X}_{1/2}.
$$

We infer that $\mathcal{F} := \mathcal{S}_{p\sqrt2}\circ\mathcal{X}_{1/2}$ is the square root of $\mathcal{E}$, i.e. that $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{F}\circ\mathcal{F}$. The map $\mathcal{F}$ can be written as

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(\rho)&=p\sqrt2\left(\frac12\rho + \frac12 X\rho X\right)\\
&=\frac{p}{\sqrt2}\rho + \frac{p}{\sqrt2}X\rho X
\end{align}
$$

and has Kraus operators

$$
V_1 = 
\frac{\sqrt{p}}{\sqrt[4]{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\quad
V_2 = 
\frac{\sqrt{p}}{\sqrt[4]{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which are proportional to the Kraus operators $U_1$ and $U_2$ of $\mathcal{E}$. In particular, if the original map $\mathcal{E}$ is trace-preserving, i.e. if $p=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, then the map is idempotent and hence its own square root.